# How to make this texture use displacement modifier?

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers, displacement

The result came out just bad, and I can not make it a round shape with a noise texture, it shows as squares instead of circles. Please advice. Thanks a lot!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Here is a similar question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/168701

Comment: Unless you're really close-up, so you can see the silhouette of the little studs, a bump-map would be much more economical, here, and make no difference, I would at least compare, to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using Displacement modifier**

- heavily subdivide (1-2 million polygons) to get enough detail
- notice the texture has a regular criss-cross pattern, it's not a random noise
- to get the 'dots' round, add Subdivision modifier *after* the Displacement modifier.

**Using nodes**

*Displacement Node* gives reasonably good results

[image]

Here's the node setup using a *Bump node*. *Displacement node* works as well, but requires a lot of geometry.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to use a modifier because of trying to avoid heavy geometry. I think this is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :).

Answer (score 4):

If you want circles, i'd suggest to use the Voronoi Texture in combination with a Color Ramp.
[image]
To get the offset from the border you will need to use the mapping node with 0.5 offset in x and y. You can play around with the scale of the voronoi texture, but there are only certain value ranges where you get the circle shapes. Important that "Randomness" is set to 0!

Also regarding the highly subdivided geometry, you can use the "Experimental" Cycles setup, where you can use adaptive subdivision.

[image]

[image: Using Voronoi and Color Ramp to get round shapes]

The picture above should be self explanatory, but important to note is that you will **have** to use the "Experimental" Cycles Engine setup to gain access to the adaptive subdivision as shown below:

[image]

Here you need to adjust the dicing scale to get a smoother result.
In the "Surface" panel option in the material, as shown below, you can set the "Displacement Only" or "Displacement and Bump".

[image: bump/displacement or both]

You can always fall back to using Bump only which does not need the "Experimental" Setting and should be a lot less strain on the system. But that would depend on how close/detailed you want to go.

Comment: Oh, that's a really elegant way to make polka dots :).

Comment: Agree with Jachym, it is a mind open way to make them. Thanks a lot!